# Makefile plugin for pycharm

Tags: makefile, pycharm

Is there any plugin for Makefiles for PyCharm? there were [C/C++](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/1373?pr=) but it is no longer supported and therefore compatible with the newest pycharm

Comment: I have same request.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Victor Kropp, one of JetBrains employees, wrote Makefile plugin that adds a bunch of nice features, and most importantly tab support. See https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9333-makefile-support

Comment: Works like a charm (pun intended). Just go to File -> Settings... -> Plugins. Click button "Browse repositories...". Start typing "makefile" in the search box. "Makefile support" plugin appears. Install and restart pycharm. Tested with pycharm community edition 2018.2.

Comment: It still working properly, as described above. Tested with PyCharm Professional Edition 2020.1

Answer (score 14):

There is now a **plugin available on the official repository**:  [`intellij-makefile`](https://github.com/kropp/intellij-makefile)

[image: native plugin]

> Fully supports GNU Make syntax.
>
> Provides:
>
> - syntax highlighting
> - keywords & target names completion
> - run configurations
> - gutter marks & context actions to run targets
> - quick-doc for ## comments on target line
> - find usages and Go To Symbol navigation for targets
> - prerequisites resolution
> - rules, variables and conditionals folding
> - quick fixes to create new rule from unresolved prerequisite and remove empty rule

---

<s>From [Dealing With Makefiles in IntelliJ](https://www.everythingfrontend.com/dealing-with-makefiles-in-intellij/~)</s>

After **considering and accepting the security risk** of **installing from an untrusted source**, you can import the `.jar` in your application.

> #### Syntax Highlighting
>
> It's turns out it is possible to create custom file types in IntelliJ,
>   I've created one for Makefiles. The number highlighting is a bit funky
>   but the rest should be good. To install it you can download this
>   settings jar:
>
> https://www.everythingfrontend.com/files/makefile.jar
>
> Then just go to `File` > `Import Settings` and import that file.
>
> #### Indent with Tabs
>
> If you have a setting to detect indentation enabled, this should just
>   work, but in case it doesn't you can install EditorConfig plugin and
>   then add the following to your .editorconfig settings:
>
> ```
> # Override for Makefile
> [{Makefile, makefile, GNUmakefile}]
> indent_style = tab
> indent_size = 4
> ```

Comment: Can you please explain how this answer is relevant? The question is about PyCharm, not IntelliJ.

Comment: @AmirKatz Pycharm and IntelliJ use the same base, they are  made by [Jetbrains](https://www.jetbrains.com/)

Comment: I know they are, but I think it would be more helpful to create a new question which is only about IntelliJ and move your answer there. IMO, someone who is using PyCharm is clearly using Python and he/she will not want to hack jar files inside PyCharm.

Comment: @AmirKatz the question is exactly about this scenario: a Pycharm user that needed support of Makefile which I am and had this same requirement on a Python/JS/DevOps project. Moreover, importing a *.jar file containing settings is a feature of Jetbrains products (Pycharm included) so this is 100% legitimate.

Comment: @AmirKatz Edouard is correct - PyCharm and IntelliJ (and a ton of other tools) are all basically the same editor with a different set of features and plugins activated. His answer is perfectly valid!

Answer (score 6):

**Updated**: as stated by Amir Katz: from PyCharm 2017 and onwards adding a TextMate bundle is under **Settings->Editor->TextMate Bundles.**

From PyCharm 2.7 and onwards another option would be to use PyCharm's TextMate bundles support: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PYH/TextMate+Bundles+in+PyCharm

You can download the TextMate Makefile bundle here: https://github.com/textmate/make.tmbundle and then install it in PyCharm.

Comment: That's exactly what i was looking for. Thanks !

Comment: Please note that the first link In the answer above has not been updated for **PyCharm 2017**. In this version, adding a TextMate bundle is under __Settings->Editor->TextMate Bundles__.

Answer (score 2):

For **Pycharm 2018** and **Ubuntu OS**,

Go to `File > Settings> Plugins`

Now search for `Makefile support`,

install it (you will need to reboot upon installation).

Comment: I upvoted this one and the one above.  This all you need for any jetbrains product and above is the in-depth answer.